# js unix timestamp - set minutes, seconds, milliseconds to zero for resulting timestamp of its hour

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

Given a unix timestamp such as 1424321864000 (Thu Feb 19 2015 04:57:44 GMT+0000) I would like to convert this to 1424318400000 (Thu Feb 19 2015 04:00:00 GMT+0000).

In other words I want to keep the timestamp exactly as is just remove the minutes, seconds, milliseconds from it.  Whatever timestamp is input would return the same timestamp for exactly that day/time 'on its hour'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of doing this. A library such as [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) can handle this in a fairly straight-forward method:

```
const topOfHour = DateTime.fromMillis(initialTimestamp).startOf('hour');
```

There's also a matching `endOf` function if you need that.

The pure-javascript method works too but is a little messy:

```
const initialDate = new Date(initialTimestamp);
const zeroMilliseconds = new Date(initialDate.setMilliseconds(0));
const zeroSeconds = new Date(zeroMilliseconds.setSeconds(0));
const startOfHour = new Date(zeroSeconds.setMinutes(0));
```

I want to acknowledge user756659's comment with some slightly more verbose code that I missed when checking documentation.

```
const initialDate = new Date(initialTimestamp);
const startOfHour = new Date(initialDate.setMinutes(0, 0, 0))
```

It could be pared down to a one-liner, but I'm keeping it verbose here for readability.

Comment: `var initialTimestamp = 1424321864000;
const initialDate = new Date(initialTimestamp);
const newDate = new Date(initialDate.setMinutes(0, 0, 0));
console.log(initialDate);
console.log(newDate.getTime());`

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of the JavaScript [Date instance methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#instance_methods) to do that, such as [setSeconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setSeconds) and [setMinutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes):

```js
const newDate = new Date(1424321864000);
console.log(newDate.getTime());
newDate.setMilliseconds(0);
newDate.setSeconds(0);
newDate.setMinutes(0);
console.log(newDate.getTime());
```